# phpbb template edits will not show up

Tags: templates, phpbb3

I am working on a phpbb design. I have a local install with a duplicated database of the original site. **I have no access to the administration panel since I am not an admin on the original site.**

Changes made to the CSS would not show on the page, so I edited the file /style.php and forced recompiling CSS by setting $recompile to true. That solved the issue.

However, I am now trying to make changes to the HTML, because the phpbb semantics is one of the worst I have ever seen, and most elements don't have classnames.

When making changes to template files (let's say to the "prosilver" default theme), those changes won't show on the page. For example if I add classnames to certain elements, those classnames will not appear on the page.

I know that the problem comes from phpbb caching templates, and I tried forcing recaching by setting $recache to true in /style.php, but that didn't work.

Thanks for any help !

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the server via ftp or your hosts control panel, go into the `/cache` directory and delete everything EXCEPT `.htaccess` and `index.htm`. This will have the same effect as clearing the cache via the ACP and will force the templates to recompile.